# C++ copy vector range before erase

Tags: c++

I have

```
std::vector v_1;
std::vector v_2;
```

and I want to delete some elements in v_1 but store them in vector v_2 before doing so. Something along the lines

```
auto deleteIf = [](auto& x) {return x.checkDelete();}
auto it = std::remove_if(v_1.begin(), v_1.end(), deleteIf);
// how can I efficiently copy elements it to v_1 end to v2?
v1.erase(it, v_2.end());
```

How can I most efficiently copy the elements that will be erased to v_2?

Comment: move the elements from one vector to the other

Comment: `remove_if` makes no promises about the state of the elements not in the new range.

Comment: @T.C. thanks for highlighting this. I assumed remove_if would do what partition actually does and just be weirdly named

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot rely on `remove_if` to keep your elements intact. From [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) :

> [...] Iterators pointing to an element between the new logical end and the physical end of the range are still dereferenceable, but the elements themselves have unspecified values [...]

You have to somehow move them.

You can [partition](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition) your vector and than split it into two:

```
std::vector<type> v_1;
std::vector<type> v_2;

auto split_check = [](auto&) { x.checkDelete() };

// stable_partition will keep the order. if not required use std::partition
auto it = std::stable_partition(v_1.begin(), v_1.end(), split_check);

v_2.insert(v2.end(), it, v_1.end());
v_1.erase(it, v_1.end());
```

[running example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/19b8ac9bdb97c7dc).

<sub>I just realized the duplicate answer from **T.C.** mentions the exact same thing... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯</sub>

Comment: still thanks for the answer. works well